# How should events be unit tested in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, events

I have defined two events with custom event arguments and associated raising methods.  Now I wonder what and how the event should be tested.  How should I analyze the code to find candidates for unit testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I test events is as follows:

Suppose this is your object:

```
public class MyEventRaiser
{
    public event EventHandler<string> MyEvent = delegate { };

    public void Process(string data)
    {
        // do something interestuing

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            this.MyEvent(this, data + " at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore **your Subject Under Test is: `MyEventRaiser`** and you want to test the method `Process`. You need to test that the event is raised when certain conditions are met, otherwise, the event should not be raised.

To do it, I use this framework (that I use **always in my tests**) [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/), this framewrok can be used with any test engine like MSTest, NUnit, MSpec, XUnit, etc

The tests look like:

```
[TestClass]
public class CustomEventsTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void my_event_should_be_raised()
    {
        var sut = new MyEventRaiser();

        sut.MonitorEvents();

        sut.Process("Hello");

        sut.ShouldRaise("MyEvent").WithSender(sut);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void my_event_should_not_be_raised()
    {
        var sut = new MyEventRaiser();

        sut.MonitorEvents();

        sut.Process(null);

        sut.ShouldNotRaise("MyEvent");
    }
}
```

You need to use the following namespaces:

```
using FluentAssertions;
using FluentAssertions.EventMonitoring;
```